# Как сделать всплывающие подсказки (tooltips) с затемненным background? Swift

Tags: swift

Задача следующая - нужно сделать всплывающие окна при нажатии кнопки "Info" и что бы поочередно при нажатии на само всплывающее окно напротив объекта открывалось другое. Примерно изобразил это на рисунке. Искал подобные проекты на github, но там в основном проекты на objective c. Интегрировать в свой проект так и не получилось. Может у кого то есть наработки или кто подскажет как это можно осуществить. Заранее благодарю Вас =)
Вот изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Нажимаем кнопку "Info";
2) Затемняется экран кроме нужных обьектов. Например кнопки;
3) Появляется первое всплывающее окно напротив самой кнопки "Info" и объясняет что это подсказки и при нажатии на окно, включится следующая подсказка;
Получится некий маленький тур-гайд по приложению.

Answer (score 0):

Можете глянуть довольно хорошую библиотеку:

[Instructions](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions)

Настраивается легко, результат должен Вам подойти.

Написана на Swift.

Comment: Благодарю вас =)

Comment: Пытался установить данную библиотеку и столкнулся с проблемой при внесении данных в Cartfile - Carthage. Ошибка Parse error. Перерыл все, решения не нашел. Может есть какие то подробные инструкции в картинках или еще что то. Создал вопрос на эту тему тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691767/Ошибка-в-cartfile-swift-parse-error/691812#691812