# Ошибка в Cartfile Swift (Parse error)

Tags: swift

Хотел применить библиотеку [Github - Instructions](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions) для всплывающих подсказок (Cocoapods, Cartage). С установкой Cocoapods не было никаких проблем, а вот с добавлением и примененим условий в Cartfile возникла ошибка: 
Parse error: expected version in line: github "ephread/Instructions" ~> "1.0.0"
Перерыл все, не нашел результата, переустанавливал несколько раз - не помогло. Так же попробовал добавить файл в Embedded Binaries, ну и это не дало результата. И в самом проекте ошибки. Может кто подскажет как правильно устанавливать подобные вещи?

[image: Вот как это выглядит в Терминале]

Comment: Попробуйте убрать кавычки в версии. ~> 1.0.0

Comment: Убрал кавычки и вышла ошибка: Failed to read file or folder at /Users/dnywka/Documents/EvCalc/Cartfile.resolved: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Cartfile.resolved” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/dnywka/Documents/EvCalc/Cartfile.resolved, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd01bc6de20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 0):

Ставите CocoaPods(https://cocoapods.org/), открываете в терминале корневую папку вашего проекта, вбиваете команду `pod init`. В папке проекта должен появиться podfile. Открываете текстовым редактором, добавляете список необходимых зависимостей

к примеру:

```
 target 'YourProjectTarget' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Instructions', '~> 1.0.0'
 end
```

После команду `pod install`. Открываете файл с расширением xcworkspace,

Comment: но с podfile проблем не возникло, с этим я справился. Трудности возникли с Carthage и Cartfile. Не получается совершить carthage build